# sailsjs error handling when creating two models

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sails.js

I'm pretty new two nodejs and sails. I'm trying to create two models inside one action. My question is how to handle the errors which can occur in both queries.

Current Code:

```
new: function (req, res) {
    var errorArray = [];
    var data = req.allParams();

        User.create({
            username: data.username,
            password: data.password,
            device_id: data.device_id,
            own_number: data.own_number,
            mobile_numbers: data.mobile_numbers
        }).exec(function (err, user) {
            if(err){
            errorArray.push(err);
            }
        });

        Mobile_number.create({
          number: data.own_number,
          number_id: this.hash(data.own_number)
        }).exec(function(err, mobile_number){
          sails.log(err);
          if(err){
            errorArray.push(err);
          }
       });

       if(errorArray.length == 0){
         return res.ok('success');
       }else {
        return res.send(errorArray.toString());
       }    
  }
```

The problem with this code is that the if at the end is handled before the queries finish. What would be the right way for to wait for the queries?

Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your code will not work because node.js is asynchronous. So you check if there are errors before functions are executed. Below are 2 solutions:

You can use [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback). If you use that it will stop executing if first method fails and it will return it's error. It it succeed it will go to second method.

```js
async.series([
        function(callback) {
            User.create({
                username: data.username,
                password: data.password,
                device_id: data.device_id,
                own_number: data.own_number,
                mobile_numbers: data.mobile_numbers
            }).exec(callback);
        },
        function(callback) {
            Mobile_number.create({
                number: data.own_number,
                number_id: this.hash(data.own_number)
            }).exec(callback);
        }
    ],
    function(error, results) {
        // error first finished 
        if(error)
            res.send('error');
        else
            res.send('success');
    }
);
```

Or you can do it traditional way with callbacks.

```js
new: function(req, res) {
    var errorArray = [];
    var data = req.allParams();

    var mobileCreateCallback = function(err, mobile_number, user) {
        sails.log(err);
        if (err) {
            errorArray.push(err);
        }

        if (errorArray.length === 0) {
            sails.log(user, mobile_number);
            return res.ok('success');
        } else {
            return res.send(errorArray.toString());
        }
    };

    var userCreateCallback = function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            errorArray.push(err);
        }

        Mobile_number.create({
            number: data.own_number,
            number_id: this.hash(data.own_number)
        }).exec(function(error, mobile_number) {
            mobileCreateCallback(error, mobile_number, user);
        });
    };

    User.create({
        username: data.username,
        password: data.password,
        device_id: data.device_id,
        own_number: data.own_number,
        mobile_numbers: data.mobile_numbers
    }).exec(userCreateCallback);
}
```

You should reed about callbacks: [callbackhell](http://callbackhell.com/) and asynchronous functions in node.js/sails.js.

Comment: which would you recommend?

Comment: @Bruno first one with async is much more elegant. But if you need both errors you need to use second one.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you very much for the explanation